# Subtração do valor atual pelo valor anterior em uma coluna específica

Tags: r, dplyr

Preciso subtrair o Bm do TIME 2016-09-01 pelo Bm anterior TIME 2016-09-01, e o mesmo paras as linhas seguintes, com os resultados dessa subtração em uma nova coluna (BGRm). Por último tentei o seguinte código:

```
censo %>% group_by(AM,Species,TIME)%>%
  summarise(INT=mean(INT,na.rm=T),Bm=mean(B,na.rm=T),BGRm=last(Bm)-first(Bm))
```

Mas os valores de BGRm estão saindo nulos:

|  | AM | Species | TIME | INT | Bm | BGRm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FF | E. coriacea | 2016-07-01 | 0 | 404.45 | 0 |
| 2 | FF | E. coriacea | 2016-09-01 | 68.9 | 405.16 | 0 |
| 3 | FF | E. coriacea | 2016-11-01 | 50.7 | 405.97 | 0 |
| 4 | FF | E. coriacea | 2017-01-01 | 62.6 | 405.13 | 0 |
| 5 | FF | E. coriacea | 2017-03-01 | 55.3 | 406.75 | 0 |

...

Alguém poderia me ajudar por gentileza?

Comment: Com os dados da pergunta vai ser sempre 0, só há um TIME 2016-09-01. Nos dados reais há mais que uma linha com cada TIME?

Comment: Tente `mutate(BGRm = Bm - lag(Bm, default = 0))`.

Comment: Olá Rui, cometi um erro na pergunta, seria 09/16 - 07/16, 11/16 - 09/16 e assim por diante. Consegui resolver usando o código que você indicou. Obrigado!